# How to query SQL Server using PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this code that I got from a website and it's connected to my SQL Server using window authentication but I'm not sure how can I choose a database and query some table?.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-Null
$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') "server instance"
$s.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$true
$s.Databases | select name, size, status
```

If I run this code, it show me a list of databases but I want to choose a database called "LitHold" and query some table from that database inside.

Comment: If you can install Modules, I would take on this module https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18256

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon, I already installed that module tho.

Comment: The module contains the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command; I would suggest having a look at that.

Comment: `DBAtools` is another very recommended module but haven't tried it personally.

Comment: Wait, I just noticed, you've tagged powershell 2? Why are you using such an old version of Powershell? That shipped with Windows 7 if I recall correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `SMO` like you have in your question, you can run queries that return data using `ExecuteWithResults()` like so:

```sh
$s =  New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "server instance"
$db = $s.Databases.Item("master")

$query = "SELECT * FROM [master].[sys].[databases] ORDER BY [name];"
$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)

# Show output
$result.Tables[0]
```

Comment: It work, thank you so much bro. really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi bro, can you please answer another question for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70705126/how-can-i-import-csv-data-in-to-my-sql-server-using-powershell